# Context compatible React hook for routing

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-hooks, react-context, hookrouter

I'm using hooks and functional components in all my react project and don't have any class component. So i want a hook to use for routing (so don't want to use react-router library). I googled and found some hooks and choose the [hookrouter](https://github.com/Paratron/hookrouter). Since the app component got re-rendered while route changes, so can't use Context to save some data along with the project. I want a routing hook that is compatible with react-context (context-provider and useContext of course). Do any one knows one? Thanks for spending your time.

Comment: The may help you :) https://medium.com/@Charles_Stover/how-to-convert-withrouter-to-a-react-hook-19bb02a29ed6

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Thank you so much, but i studied it before. The problem is it is not as simple to implement as i want

Answer (score 0):

Use useHistory hook to navigate. This hook is compatible with router dom version 5.1.0 and above.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const history = useHistory();

history.push({pathname:'/home'});
```

Comment: Thank you very much but just now i'm using `useHistory`. At the time i was writing this question, this hooks were not exist ;)